# Should we have rewards for the best answer of each quarter?

Tags: discussion, site-health, answers, community-building, site-activity

Over at Latin SE, they recently had a voting round for the [best answers of the second quarter of 2017](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303/rewarding-the-best-answers-of-the-second-quarter-of-2017). I propose that we do something similar on LLSE. The reason is that voting has been rather low this year compared to last year, and it would encourage people to go read answers and (possibly) upvote them.

I quote Joonas Ilmavirta's description from the post linked above:

> What were the best answers of the second quarter (April, May, June) of 2017? **Nominate your favorites and vote on other people's suggestions!** To nominate an answer, simply post it an answer to this question with a link and brief description of the answer.
>
> The nominated answers must have been originally posted in one of these months. To get you started, here is a search for all answers from this period with positive score. The answer doesn't have to be accepted, and it doesn't matter if it has already received a bounty.
>
> **Everyone is invited to nominate and vote!** After three weeks (**July 24**, but I make no promise about the exact time), the two nominations with the highest scores on this meta post will be declared the winners. The two winning answers will be rewarded with bounties of 100 reputation points each, from the personal reputation stashes of the moderators. (If the scores are tied, we will reward at least two answers and give out at least 200 reputation in some way.)
>
> Of course, anyone with 75 or more reputation is free to reward any answer they like at any time. Consider this contest also as an opportunity to highlight some hidden gems that received few votes but are excellent in quality.

So my questions are:

- Should we also have a quarterly best answer award?
- If yes, do we start after the third quarter or do we start an award now for the second quarter?

**Note**: I added the tag [site-health](/questions/tagged/site-health) to the question because its goal is to increase activity on the site.

**Updates**:

- I would like all mods to comment on or respond to this question.
- We may do this per half year instead of each quarter.

Comment: What if a mod gets the prize? Would a regular user help award the bounty?

Comment: Also, I would vote for a competition like this for questions as well

Comment: To the first question: there is more than one mod, but I would like to hear from each of them before we set up this type of reward system. To the second question: let's just stick to answers right now. People have been rather reticent to award bounties so far. If we don't get all the mods on board, I propose a "Hall of Fame" instead of bounties.

Comment: @AnthonyPham I second that. A separate competition for questions would encourage a good flow of new questions.

Comment: I'd be willing to donate some rep for bounties, also, I like this idea. :)

Comment: Here is [a question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2718/27264) from Movies & TV you can take an idea from.

Comment: @AJ Sure. There are similar questions on several SE sites, but there was little support for awards on our site. Hence [Nominate your favourite answers from the third quarter of 2017](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/589/800).

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe I see a reason that it was stuck on was who will reward the bounty. On that site, a mod rewards the bounty with a condition that answers by that mod cannot be nominated.

Answer (score 1):

> Should we also have a quarterly best answer award?

Why not? It would inspire people to actually try (or try harder) to make the best answers.

> If yes, do we start after the third quarter or do we start an award now for the second quarter?

Let's wait for the third quarter. I think it's too sudden to start this before knowing exactly what is the criteria for winning. Also, though we put quality first, we kinda need the rep to help since most rep right now is from upvotes on our old answers from private beta.

> If we don't get all the mods on board, I propose a "Hall of Fame" instead of bounties.

I can supply/assist-in-supplying the bounties if the moderators are a little reluctant. As my activity grows stronger, I will hopefully be able to make generous rewards. I really do think bounties are a stronger motivating factor since bounties attract quite the attention. Sure, featuring the winners might get them some upvotes, but so do bounties (which also give more rep themselves!). A combo of both like on Puzzling/PPCG (I can't remember which one or both) would greatly help.