# Nominate your favourite answers from the third quarter of 2017

Tags: discussion, blog, best-of

Please post links to your favourite answers from the third quarter of 2017 (posted between 1 July and 30 September 2017). They don't need to be somebody else's answers; you can promote your own contributions.

The idea is to compile the best answers into one or more blog posts for our currently dormant [blog](https://medium.com/language-learning-blog). You can, of course, nominate more than one answer to the same question.

(Since my [proposal to reward good answers with bounties](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/548/800) received insufficient support—only one moderator supported it, and there was a downvote to the only answer—I am trying another reward method that will hopefully also draw users to the site through the blog.)

**Update**: This question will remain "open" until Sunday 19 November.

Comment: I will be awarding the best answer anyways as a *bonus reward*.

Answer (score 3):

User [@fi12](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/91/fi12) provides insight to the [effectiveness of online courses with respect to speaking](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/3112/85).

Answer (score 0):

Since only one answer has been posted so far, I'll add some "competition", namely  [this answer](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/3002/800) to the question [Why can't I think of anything to say when someone asks how many languages I can speak?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2997/800). It explains the problem by linking it to the "jam study" that illustrated "choice overload".