# Best questions and answers from 1st and 2nd quarters of 2020

Tags: discussion, best-of

I'm reviving an idea that has been neglected since 2017. (See [Nominate your favourite answers from the third quarter of 2017](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/589/800).)

Please post links to your favourite questions and answers from the first and second quarters of 2020 (posted between 1 January and 30 June 2020). They don't need to be somebody else's answers; you can promote your own contributions.

Since votes don't always reflect quality, it would be especially worthwhile to nominate questions and answers that have received little attention in spite of their quality. And, who knows, some may even be rewarded with a bounty...

Comment: There are [81 questions](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20created%3a2020-01-01..2020-06-30) and [97 answers](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2020-01-01..2020-06-30) to choose from.