# Best questions and answers from 3rd quarter of 2020

Tags: discussion, best-of

I am continuing an idea that began in [2017](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/589/800) and that was revived [this summer](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/682/800).

Please post links to your favourite questions and answers from the third quarter of 2020 (posted between 1 July and 30 September 2020). They don't need to be somebody else's answers; you can promote your own contributions. There are [47 questions](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2020-07-01..2020-09-30) and [47 answsers](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2020-07-01..2020-09-30) to choose from.

Since votes don't always reflect quality, it would be especially worthwhile to nominate questions and answers that have received little attention in spite of their quality. And, who knows, some may even be rewarded with a bounty...